# Error to get location after push notification iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, core-location, cllocationmanager

After receive a push notification I am trying to get the current localization.

However when I start the code bellow the corelocation fails (didFailWithError) when the app is at background :(

Only works in foreground.

Why?

I already did the .plist for background configuration

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(nonnull NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(nonnull void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{

    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

        NSLog(@" Finalizado background...");

    }];

    [self handleStartMonitoringLocation];




    NSLog(@"Main Thread proceeding...");

}


-(void)handleStartMonitoringLocation{

    // location
    if (!self.shareModel) {
        self.shareModel = [LocationManager sharedManager];
        self.shareModel.afterResume = NO;
        [self.shareModel addApplicationStatusToPList:@"didFinishLaunchingWithOptions"];
    }


    [self.shareModel addApplicationStatusToPList:@"applicationDidBecomeActive"];
    //Remove the "afterResume" Flag after the app is active again.
    self.shareModel.afterResume = NO;
    //    [self.shareModel startMonitoringLocation];
    [self.shareModel startBackgroundLocationUpdates];

}



-(void)startBackgroundLocationUpdates {
    // Create a location manager object
    self.anotherLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    // Set the delegate
    self.anotherLocationManager.delegate = self;

    // Request location authorization
    [self.anotherLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

    // Set an accuracy level. The higher, the better for energy.
    self.anotherLocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    // Enable automatic pausing
    self.anotherLocationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = YES;

    // Specify the type of activity your app is currently performing
    self.anotherLocationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeFitness;

    if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"9.0")){
        // Enable background location updates
        self.anotherLocationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;

        [self.anotherLocationManager requestLocation];
    }
    else{
        // Start location updates
        [self.anotherLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    }

}


#pragma mark - CLLocationManager Delegate

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error  {

     NSLog(@"locationManager error: %@",error);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{

    NSLog(@"locationManager didUpdateLocations: %@",locations);

}
```

Comment: You need to use `requestAlwaysAuthorization` if you want to get location in the background.

Comment: I haven't seen any code related to asking for background location updates, -requestAlwaysAuthorization might be useful for your case&BTW do remember to add NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescreption key with appropriate description in info.plist